# C++ function template overloading

Tags: c++, templates

This example is from C++ templates book by Josuttis :

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <string>

 // maximum of two values of any type (call-by-reference)
 template <typename T>
 inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b)
 {
     return  a < b  ?  b : a;
 }

 // maximum of two C-strings (call-by-value)
 inline char const* max (char const* a, char const* b)
 { 
    return  std::strcmp(a,b) < 0  ?  b : a;
 }

 // maximum of three values of any type (call-by-reference)
 template <typename T>
 inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
 {
     return max (max(a,b), c);  // error, if max(a,b) uses call-by-value
 }

 int main ()
 {
   ::max(7, 42, 68);     // OK

    const char* s1 = "frederic";
    const char* s2 = "anica";
    const char* s3 = "lucas";
    ::max(s1, s2, s3);    // ERROR

}
```

He says that the reason for error in `::max(s1, s2, s3)` is that for C-strings `max(max(a,b),c)` calls `max(a,b)`  that creates a new temporary local value that may be returned by the function by reference.

I am not getting how a new local value is getting created ?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code from the book correctly? I think `inline char const* max` should be `inline char const* const& max`

Comment: The final return from `inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)` will still return a reference to a local value (pointer) that will cease to exists once max completely returns.

Comment: Jesse, the example has been taken from Josuttis's website ...  (http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/) ... Its `basics/max3a.cpp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For C-strings, this code creates a local value, i.e, a local variable that stores an address (pointer of type char const *):

std::strcmp(a,b) < 0  ?  b : a;

Hence returning a reference to this (using the template functions) leads to an error. In this case the reference of type `char const * const &` to a local is returned by the template function `max` after the C-string `max` has returned a copy. The template functions have to return pointers by value instead of reference.

The template functions need to be overloaded for pointer types.